# Why is my queue data-structure in javascript behaving the way it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

I have implemented a queue using linked list. I added a enqueue and dequeue function. As per the data structure, if after using dequeue, the item after 'front' item should become front but my code is setting 3rd item on queue as front. Please look at my code and tell me what I did wrong.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.front = null;
    this.rear = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  enqueue(value) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.length === 0) {
      this.front = newNode;
      this.rear = newNode;
    } else {
      this.front.prev = this.rear;
      this.rear = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
    
    return newNode;
  }
  dequeue() {
    if (!this.front) {
      return null;
    }
    if (this.front === this.rear) {
      this.rear = null;
    } else {
      this.front = this.front.prev;
      this.length--;
    }
    return this.front;
  }
}

const myQueue = new Queue();

console.log('myQueue.enqueue(5) : ', myQueue.enqueue(5));
console.log('myQueue : ', myQueue);

console.log('myQueue.enqueue(6) : ', myQueue.enqueue(6));
console.log('myQueue : ', myQueue);

console.log('myQueue.enqueue(7) : ', myQueue.enqueue(7));
console.log('myQueue : ', myQueue);

console.log('myQueue.dequeue() : ', myQueue.dequeue());
console.log('myQueue : ', myQueue);

console.log('myQueue.dequeue() : ', myQueue.dequeue());
console.log('myQueue : ', myQueue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You have no "storage" every element that's put gets lost irrevocably after a subsequent enqueue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answer parts ...

1. the original first answer,
2. and the second updated answer that deals with the OP's linked-list.

#### 1st Answer

There was an incrementation bug `this.length-` instead of `this.length--;`.

And how about using a `Queue` approach that encapsulates a list structure like an `Array`?..

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}

class Queue {
  constructor() {

    const queue = [];

    this.front = null;
    this.rear = null;
    this.length = queue.length;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'enqueue', {
      value: function (value) {

        const node = new Node(value);
        const itemCount = queue.push(node);

        node.prev = queue[itemCount - 2] || null;

        this.front = queue[0];
        this.rear = queue[itemCount - 1];
        this.length = itemCount;

        return node;
      }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'dequeue', {
      value: function () {

        const node = queue.shift() || null;
        const itemCount = queue.length;

        this.front = queue[0] || null;
        this.rear = queue[itemCount - 1] || null;
        this.length = itemCount;

        return node;
      }
    });
  }
}

const queue = new Queue();

console.log('queue.enqueue(5) : ', queue.enqueue(5));
console.log('queue.enqueue(6) : ', queue.enqueue(6));
console.log('queue.enqueue(7) : ', queue.enqueue(7));

console.log('queue.dequeue() : ', queue.dequeue());
console.log('queue.dequeue() : ', queue.dequeue());

console.log(queue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

#### 2nd Iteration with Linked List Approach

A proper dequeuing process relies rather on properly maintained `next` links. The `prev` linking is just a *nice to have* feature on top ... proof of concept ...

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = null;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.front = null;
    this.rear = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  enqueue(value) {
    const enqueuedNode = new Node(value);

    if (this.rear !== null) {
      this.rear.next = enqueuedNode;
    }
    enqueuedNode.prev = this.rear;

    const itemCount = ++this.length;
    if (itemCount === 1) {

      this.front = enqueuedNode;
    }
    this.rear = enqueuedNode;

    return enqueuedNode;
  }
  dequeue() {
    const dequeuedNode = this.front;
    if (dequeuedNode !== null) {

      dequeuedNode.prev = null;
      // dequeuedNode.next = null;
    }
    this.front = dequeuedNode && dequeuedNode.next;

    const itemCount = --this.length;
    if (itemCount === 0) {

      this.rear = null;

    } else if (itemCount <= -1) {

      this.length = 0;
    }
    return dequeuedNode;
  }
}

const queue = new Queue();

console.log('queue.enqueue(5) : ', queue.enqueue(5));
console.log('queue : ', queue);

console.log('queue.enqueue(6) : ', queue.enqueue(6));
console.log('queue : ', queue);

console.log('queue.enqueue(7) : ', queue.enqueue(7));
console.log('queue : ', queue);

console.log('queue.dequeue() : ', queue.dequeue());
console.log('queue : ', queue);

console.log('queue.dequeue() : ', queue.dequeue());
console.log('queue : ', queue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you peter for answering,I corrected 'length--' I know how to implement a queue using a array but I wanted try it with linked list. Can you please rerun my code and add one more enqueue call. You will notice Front's 'priv' become the 4th item. Where as it should have been Front's 'priv' should point toward 2nd item.

Comment: @AjayJarhad ... there is an update with a second answer part that takes the OP's ***link list only*** approach into account.

Comment: Thank you Peter, it is much better to use doubly linked list.